# How to run an audio in python charm?

Tags: python, audio, module, pycharm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhbsH.png)
facing the above issue

I try to use the pip install Playsound to download the latest version of Playsound

```
 File "C:\Users\Farhad Rashid Reshi\PycharmProjects\PythonHarry\hello_world.py", line 13, in <module>
    play soundd('C:\\Users\\Farhad Rashid Reshi\\Downloads\\audio.mp3');
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Farhad Rashid Reshi\PycharmProjects\PythonHarry\venv\Lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 44, in _playsoundWin
    _playsoundWin(tempPath, block)
  File "C:\Users\Farhad Rashid Reshi\PycharmProjects\PythonHarry\venv\Lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 73, in _playsoundWin
in commandmmplayplay {}{}'.format(sound, ' wait' if block else ''))
  File "C:\Users\Farhad Rashid Reshi\PycharmProjects\PythonHarry\venv\Lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 64, in winCommand
    raise PlaysoundExcexception messageMessage)
playsound.PlaysoundException:
    Error 259 for command:
        play "C:\Users\FARHAD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\PSaamnph4b.mp3" wait
    The driver cannot recognize the specified command parameter.
```

I have tried my ways to solve the issue but still facing the same error.

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To play audio in Python, you can use the pygame library. Here's how you can install it and play audio in a Python script:

Install pygame:

You can install pygame using pip, the Python package manager. Open your terminal or command prompt and run the following command:

```
pip install pygame
```

Write a Python script to play audio:

Here's a simple example script that plays an audio file using pygame:

```
import pygame

def play_audio(file_path):
    # Initialize Pygame mixer
    pygame.mixer.init()

    # Load the audio file
    pygame.mixer.music.load(file_path)

    # Play the audio file
    pygame.mixer.music.play()

    # Keep the script running while the audio is playing
    while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
        pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    audio_file = "path/to/your/audio/file.mp3"  # Change this to the path of your audio file
    play_audio(audio_file)
```

Replace "path/to/your/audio/file.mp3" with the path to your audio file.

Run the Python script:

Save the script with a .py extension (e.g., play_audio.py). Then, run the script using the Python interpreter: